# Massive insert query shifting somewhere

Tags: mysql

Is there any tool or any easy accessible way to get a mysql insert to have the fields and the values to be entered listed side by side ?

I have some big inserts with over 80 fields and at some point they start to shift, meaning the value is one ahead or behind of the field and all gets messed up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a key value array...

```
$arr = array(
        'name' => 'something',
        'email' => 'lol@rofl.com',
        'quote' => 'hi there'
    );

$insert = "INSERT INTO `table` (`" . implode("`,`", array_keys($arr)) ."`) VALUES ('". implode("','", array_values($arr)) . "')";
```

This is just a quick example. In reality you'll really want to properly sanitize these inputs and consider reserved words, etc. But the basic idea is that this way there won't be a disconnect since array_keys and array_values count will be equal.

Now, all you'd need to do is make sure your array is built as expected.